# Detect Shared IP

Tags: asp.net

I'm implementing feature which should ban users by IP. Is there any way to identify - is client uses Dedicated IP or Shared IP?

Questions let me know.
Thanks.

EDITED:

Or maybe someone have experience how to handle this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to identify - is client uses Dedicated IP or Shared IP?

No, there is no way. This information is not part of the TCP nor the HTTP protocol and thus never sent to the server. All you could get is the client IP that was used to send the request to your site.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to reverse-lookup the DNS name from this IP and then do some heuristics on the name if it is auto-generated name like:

```
\d+[-.]\d+[-.]\d+[-.]\d+[-.](ppp|a?dsl)(\.[-a-z0-9]+)+
```

but this will give many false positives.